# How can we implement Pagination using Javascript in simple HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

I'm trying to create an HTML table with pagination. I am calling a JSON data using a GET api and binding it as a dynamic table format. Pagination is handling in API by passing the page number. How can we simply handle the pagination in HTML Page with JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parent Child Mapping</title>
    <style>
        th,
        td,
        p,
        input {
            font: 14px Verdana;
        }

        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: solid 1px #DDD;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 2px 3px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        th {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Create Table From JSON" />
    <p id="showData"></p>
    <div id="" class="pager-nav"></div>
</body>

<script>
    function CreateTableFromJSON() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var myBooks = [];
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
                myBooks = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                console.log("ok" + myBooks);

                // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
                // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
                var col = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
                    for (var key in myBooks[i]) {
                        console.log("myBooks..", myBooks[i])
                        if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                            col.push(key);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
                var table = document.createElement("table");

                // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

                var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

                for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                    var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
                    th.innerHTML = col[i];
                    tr.appendChild(th);
                }

                // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
                for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
                    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
                    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                        tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
                    }
                }

                // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
                var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
                divContainer.innerHTML = "";
                divContainer.appendChild(table);
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</html>
```

This is the html code i have added for dynamic table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a row of buttons under your dynamic table, each of which correspond to the page number of results in your API.

Set an `onclick` event on the buttons to execute a GET request to your API with the correct parameters i.e. pageNumber, resultsPerPage -- this depends on how the API is set up.

Then you are effectively doing the same thing you are doing now, but with specific results based on page number and number of results/rows per page.

You can also cache the results to avoid further round trips on subsequent clicks of a previously clicked page number.